# Continuous action and space in DQN with Gym.spaces.Box?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, box, openai-gym, dqn

I wanna investigate 3 functions in comparison with my cost function in a specific period.
my action and observation spaces are continuous. how do I solve this error?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import gym 
from gym import spaces
from gym.spaces import Tuple , Box
import gym
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense  
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation  
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent

class Example3(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
    # =============================================================
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(
            low=np.array([0,0])
            ,high=np.array([10,100])
            ,dtype=np.float32)
        lower_bound=np.array([-4,-1,0],dtype=np.float32,)
        upper_bound=np.array([2,1,10],dtype=np.float32,)        
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(lower_bound, upper_bound, 
dtype=np.float32)
    
        self.time=100
        self.state = None
        self.x=10

    #==================================
        self.E1report=np.array([])
        self.actionreport=np.array([])
        self.E2report=np.array([])
        self.E3report=np.array([])
        self.Costreport=np.array([])
    #==================================

    def step(self, action):
    #==================================
        self.actionreport=np.append(self.actionreport,action)
        np.savetxt('ActionReport.txt',self.actionreport)
    #==================================
        E1,E2,E3= self.state
    
        self.time-=1
    ##=================================
    ## equations
    #
    # E1=(-np.sin(x))/2*(x)
    # E2=np.sin(x)
    # cost=x**2/10
    # =================================


    
        theta=action[0]+action[1]
    #=============================================


        E1=(-4*np.sin(theta))/(theta)
        E2=np.sin(theta)
        E3=(theta)**2/10
        cost=np.sin(theta)+theta+theta**2/2+2022
    
    #====================================================
        self.E1report=np.append(self.E1report,E1)
        np.savetxt('E1Report.txt',self.E1report)
    
        self.E2report=np.append(self.E2report,E2)
        np.savetxt('E2Report.txt',self.E2report)

        self.E3report=np.append(self.E3report,E3)
        np.savetxt('E3Report.txt',self.E3report)

        self.Costreport=np.append(self.Costreport,cost)
        np.savetxt('CostReport.txt',self.Costreport)

    
    #====================================================
        self.state = (E1,E2,E3)


        Myif = bool(-cost<2025)

        if Myif:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = 0
    
        if self.time==0:
            done=True
        else:
            done=False 

        info={}        

        return np.array(self.state, dtype=np.float32), reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
    
        E1=np.random.uniform(-4,2)
        E2=np.random.uniform(-1,1)
        E3=np.random.uniform(0,10)
    
        self.state=(E1,E2,E3)
    
        self.time=100
        done=False

        return np.array(self.state, dtype=np.float32)

    def render():
        pass 

env=Example3()
nb_actions = env.action_space.shape[0]

# ============================
model = Sequential()

model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape))

model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))

print(model.summary())

# ======================================
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory  
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=20000, window_length=1)

from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy

policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), 
                              attr='eps',
                              value_max=1.,
                              value_min=.1,
                              value_test=.05,
                              nb_steps=20000)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10,
               target_model_update=100, policy=policy)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae']) 
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=10000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

in random iteration, my env works but in DQN have an error. 
 
in DQN actions are 0 or 1 !!! 
and Error : TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

As given in the previous answer DQN is not designed for this action space. There are however agents that are, and for example the [Stable Baselines 3 library](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) provides several agents that can deal with continuous action spaces out of the box.

A nice overview over which agents are suited for continuous action spaces is given here:
https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/algos.html